# How to make interface in adapter class

Tags: java, android

I am making interface in adapter class but it is giving me error that interface expected here.How can I implement interface in adapter class.I made the adapter and main class but showing me error that interface is expected here.  [image]

```
public class Dashboard_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Dashboard_Model_File>  implements RecyclerSwipeAdapter<Dashboard_Adapter.SimpleViewHolder>  {
    ArrayList<Dashboard_Model_File> dashboard_model_files_obj;

    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public Dashboard_Adapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Dashboard_Model_File> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        dashboard_model_files_obj = objects;
    }

    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/cabin.regular.ttf");

    public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
        TextView textViewPos;
        TextView textViewData;
        Button buttonDelete;

        public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(com.daimajia.swipe.R.id.swipe);
            textViewPos = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(com.daimajia.swipe.R.id.position);
            textViewData = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(com.daimajia.swipe.R.id.text_data);
            buttonDelete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(com.daimajia.swipe.R.id.delete);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onItemSelected: " + textViewData.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "onItemSelected: " + textViewData.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public Dashboard_Adapter(Dashboard dashboard, ArrayList<Dashboard_Model_File> dashboard_model_file_arraylist) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // convert view = design

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            holder.title_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_view);
            holder.desc_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc_view);
            holder.url_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.url_view);

            holder.bookmark_id_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_id);
            holder.alternate_id_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.alternate_id);
            holder.bookmark_file_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_file);
            holder.mode_holder = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mode_id);

            holder.swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) v.findViewById(com.daimajia.swipe.R.id.swipe);
            holder.textViewPos = (TextView) v.findViewById(com.daimajia.swipe.R.id.position);
            holder.textViewData = (TextView) v.findViewById(com.daimajia.swipe.R.id.text_data);
            holder.buttonDelete = (Button) v.findViewById(com.daimajia.swipe.R.id.delete);


            holder.title_holder.setTypeface(font1); holder.title_holder.setTextSize(16.0f);
            holder.desc_holder.setTypeface(font1); holder.desc_holder.setTextSize(14.0f);
            holder.url_holder.setTypeface(font1); holder.url_holder.setTextSize(10.0f);


            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(dashboard_model_files_obj.get(position).getImage());
        holder.title_holder.setText(dashboard_model_files_obj.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.desc_holder.setText(dashboard_model_files_obj.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.url_holder.setText(dashboard_model_files_obj.get(position).getUrl());

        return v;

    }

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(com.daimajia.swipe.R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
       return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder,final int position) {
        String item = mDataset.get(position);
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SimpleSwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(layout.findViewById(com.daimajia.swipe.R.id.trash));
            }
        });
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.setOnDoubleClickListener(new SwipeLayout.DoubleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick(SwipeLayout layout, boolean surface) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "DoubleClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        viewHolder.buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
                mDataset.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataset.size());
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                // Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted " + viewHolder.textViewData.getText().toString() + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(com.daimajia.swipe.R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView title_holder;
        public TextView desc_holder;
        public TextView url_holder;

        public TextView bookmark_file_holder;
        public TextView alternate_id_holder;
        public TextView bookmark_id_holder;
        public TextView mode_holder;

        public TextView txtCategory;

        SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
        TextView textViewPos;
        TextView textViewData;
        Button buttonDelete;

    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage)
        {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: better post the code instead of snap shot

Comment: your are probably trying to implement a class instead of interface

Comment: The main problem is that you are mix too different adapters .... The one used by RecyclerView and the one userd by AdapterView(fx. ListView) ... you cannot use both ...

Comment: @selvin I needed to implement the RecyclerView in the adapter class,can you help me how can I implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not making an interface, you are trying to implement one. And as per the error it seems like this interface does not exist.